# Dropzone and asp elements

Tags: asp.net, webforms, dropzone.js, runatserver

i'm quite new developing for asp.net and found a problem i can't figure it out. 
My .aspx look like the follow:

```
<form action="#" class="" runat="server" >
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCombo" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</form>

<div class="clsbox-1" runat="server">
    <div class="dropzone clsbox" id="mydropzone">
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see i have a dropdownlist that i will populate on page_load and a dropzone inside a div (i need to be this way).

```
<script>
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$("#mydropzone").dropzone({
    url: "WebForm1.aspx?param=1",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFilesize: 0.5,
    dictDefaultMessage: 'drag and drop',
    dictResponseError: 'Error uploading file!'
});
<script>
```

this is the script that make div like a dropzone, i'm not sure if the url is right though.
The problems comes when in the page_load part, since i need to populate the dropdownlist on page load, 
when i try to upload a file via dropzone it will be sent as postback and enter in the 'if' and populate again the combobox, reseting the value that was selected.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
       loadCombo(); //populate ddlCombo
    }
    string aux = ddlCombo.SelectedValue.ToString();//this will have the first item

   //processing file...
}
```

Please let me know if there is any fancy way to do this because i can't figure it out!

**EDIT:**
I don't understand why if i send within a form it work as intended:

```
<form action="#" class="dropzone" runat="server" >
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCombo" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <div class="clsbox-1 " id="mydropzone" runat="server">
        <div class="clsbox" >
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When i upload a file here it doesn't send as post back. 
Thx you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dropzone url parameter should be to a different page/httphandler/controller you have created to accept the upload and save it to a file (or whatever you want to do with it).  You could technically use the page you're currently on, but it'd be a little trickier in your situation as you'd need to detect what caused the postback and handle appropriately (ie don't reset the dropdown).

I would recommend using an HttpHandler instead of a normal page for receiving the files.  Here's an [example](https://codepedia.info/using-dropzone-js-file-image-upload-in-asp-net-webform-c/) of one.

Comment: like this? : **url: "WebForm_safeFiles.aspx"**, doesnt send anything to that page, also tried: **Method: "get"**, nothing change :(

Comment: It would need to include the path if it's not in the same location as the current page.  You can use / to start from the site root like "/folder/filename.aspx".  I would use the F12 dev tools and see if you can see the request going out when you drop a file.  I'll also update my answer with a reference link.

Comment: THX !!! now its working, lol feel pretty dumb but i needed to write "/webform_safeFiles.apx" gonna try now the handler you suggest, THX again :)